# Расположить дивы в нужном порядке

Tags: css3, html5

Нужно исправить в блоке *(.hor)* : див Y *положить* в пустое место за дивом X, т.е. справа от него. Править стилями. Если вносить изменения в структуру, например, добавлять/менять местами дивы, - то делать это синхронно со структурой
блока *(.ver)*, так, чтобы не поломать его текущее представление. Спасибо.

---

```html
<body style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 10px;">
<div class="ver">
<div id="aaa" style="width: 146px; height: 34px; background-color: #F3E7D8;">A</div>
<div id="bbb" style="width: 146px; height: 84px; background-color: goldenrod;">B</div>
<div id="ccc" style="float: left; width: 86px; height: 40px; background-color: lightgreen;">C</div>
<div id="def" style="float: left; width: 60px; height: 40px; background-color: lightblue;">DEF</div>
<div id="ggg" style="width: 146px; height: 174px; background-color: #ccc;">G</div>
<div id="xxx" style="display: none;">X</div>
<div id="yyy" style="display: none;">Y</div>
<div id="hhh" style="width: 146px; height: 18px; background-color: khaki;">H</div>
</div>
<br><hr><br>
<div class="hor">
<div id="a" style="width: 258px; height: 34px; background-color: #F3E7D8;">A</div>
<div id="b" style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 114px; background-color: goldenrod;">B</div>
<div id="c" style="display: none;">C</div>
<div id="d" style="display: none;">DEF</div>
<div id="g" style="float: left; width: 58px; height: 114px; background-color: #ccc;">G</div>
<div id="x" style="margin-top: 114px; width: 200px; height: 40px; background-color: lightgreen;">X</div>
<div id="y" style="float: left; width: 58px; height: 40px; background-color: lightblue;">Y</div>
<div id="h" style="width: 258px; height: 18px; background-color: khaki;">H</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Делал, заменой, так : <div id="y" style="margin-top: -40px; margin-left: 200px; float: left; width: 58px; height: 40px; background-color: lightblue;">Y</div>

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body style="margin-left: 30px; margin-top: 10px;">
<div class="ver">
<div id="aaa" style="width: 146px; height: 34px; background-color: #F3E7D8;">A</div>
<div id="bbb" style="width: 146px; height: 84px; background-color: goldenrod;">B</div>
<div id="ccc" style="float: left; width: 86px; height: 40px; background-color: lightgreen;">C</div>
<div id="def" style="float: left; width: 60px; height: 40px; background-color: lightblue;">DEF</div>
<div id="ggg" style="width: 146px; height: 174px; background-color: #ccc;">G</div>
<div id="xxx" style="display: none;">X</div>
<div id="yyy" style="display: none;">Y</div>
<div id="hhh" style="width: 146px; height: 18px; background-color: khaki;">H</div>
</div>

<br><hr><br>

<div class="hor">
<div id="a" style="width: 258px; height: 34px; background-color: #F3E7D8;">A</div>
<div id="b" style="float: left; width: 200px; height: 114px; background-color: goldenrod;">B</div>
<div id="c" style="display: none;">C</div>
<div id="d" style="display: none;">DEF</div>
<div id="g" style="float: left; width: 58px; height: 114px; background-color: #ccc;">G</div>
<div id="x" style="float: left; margin-top: 114px; margin-left: -258px; width: 200px; height: 40px; background-color: lightgreen; ">X</div>
<div id="y" style="float: left; margin-top: 114px; margin-left: -58px; width: 58px; height: 40px; background-color: lightblue;">Y</div>
<div id="h" style="width: 258px; height: 18px; background-color: khaki;">H</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо, с той правкой, что я привёл выше, - получается с цветом у дива id="h". У Вас без, походу он съехал вверх ..